# How to control robot in simulation (Gazebo 7.1.0)

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i need to show one example in gazebo simulator.how to include any model in gazebo till i know, but i cant proceed further how to control that robot and give input to it.
can anyone help me out on that.
i have Kinetic Ros installed.
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248523/how-to-control-robot-in-simulation-(gazebo-7.1.0)/) by [abhay2302](https://answers.ros.org/users/28289/abhay2302/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-11-21**:
Do any of the [gazebo tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials) help?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-21**:
I've updated the title a bit: no need for caps, and this seems to describe better what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, you need a model. I assume that you are familiar with URDF and XACRO. After developing model, you need to access joint states (which can be accessed by ROS-Control Package). Once, you have joint states, you can write your ROS Node in C++ or Python by first subscribing to that states and then generating ros torque. You can study [this](https://github.com/JoshMarino/gazebo_and_ros_control#Torque%20Control) link and it will be very helpful to you. I am also currently in the process of doing it but so far have not succeeded. You can see my discussion on this [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/246767/writing-robot-dynamics-based-control-in-ros/).

---

Originally posted by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) with karma: 167 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhay2302](https://answers.ros.org/users/28289/abhay2302/) on 2016-11-22**:
thank you so much. i am new to ROS so please guide me once you are done